# Understanding Solr MoreLikeThis Result

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I'm on my way to learn to use Solr.

Im learning to use MoreLikeThis right now. and if I doing Query, which is like this

http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=terbang&indent=on&mlt=true&mlt.fl=entry

I get a more like this result like this

```
<lst name="moreLikeThis"> 
 <result name="67244" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="67250" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="146" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="3993" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="11758" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="14828" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="20820" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="23336" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="24267" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
 <result name="24779" numFound="0" start="0"/> 
</lst>
```

I dont really understand whats the meaning of the "name" attribute. And why is there many results with different name if its not found anything anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers in the `name` attribute are the unique keys of the documents in the results.